# Oddly some times value float value returns 0

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm a beginner at php trying to solve usage of PDO in PHP...

I have a PDO query: usually it returns correct value (integer 1) but sometimes i don't know how, it returns (0 or null) it happens randomly and no idea why.

Server windows based. Double checked database.. all Multiplier values (integer 1)

```
$q = $db->prepare("SELECT Multiplier,Balance FROM buoys WHERE ID=:ID");

$aID = $_POST['ID'];
$aFishValue = (float)0.4;

$q->execute(array(':ID' => $aID));
$res = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 

$aEvent = (integer)$res->Multiplier; // Some How this value some times returns 0 but all values in database integer 1.
$aBuoyBalance = (float)$res->Balance;

$aFishValue = (float)$aFishValue * (float)$aEvent;
```

Most of the time `$aFishValue` returns correctly but some times returns null. I'm totally stuck and googled for hours... No idea what to do next.

Comment: Random fun fact you don't need to specify (float) when you're doing something like $value = 0.4; PHP knows it's a float. Generally the only time you should have a reason to declare a variable type is if the data could possibly be manipulated and/or return something other than the expected type. I.e. if a user can input a $_GET id, i'd do something like $id = (int) $_GET['id']; In your case it's pointless though.

Comment: plus, the floats are duplicated. for your final multiplication, you've essentially got `(float)(float)$aFishValue`. And how about sharing what exact values are giving you the `0` result? We're not psychic and have no idea what values you're fetching from the db.

Comment: added (float) part when everything else fails.. also cant use GET ID informaton cannot be revealed thanks for answers i will use some other forums which can give me some example.. about variables. good day.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that you could check:

```
$q->execute(array(':ID' => $aID));
$res = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

On both of the above statements, the return should be checked for any error event